# Field/Property not found on data source

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, aspxgridview

I am updating an older program which collects information from different tables (using stored procedures) and displays them on an ASPxGridView. I've added three more columns and tried to bind them to the GridView. However, I've been getting a 'field/property not found' [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TAur.png) and cannot proceed.

At first, I thought that the data was not being retrieved, but debugging showed that the List object I was using to populate the ASPxGridView did contain the data that I wanted to add.

```
protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CommentsDataSource.SelectParameters.Clear();
   CommentsDataSource.SelectMethod = "SelectCommentsByProject";
   CommentsDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("pProjectId", System.Data.DbType.String, searchStringTextBox.Text.Trim());
   CommentsDataSource.Databind();
}
```

There are several other options for the search, but I'm chiefly concerned with getting at least one working before tackling the rest.

```
private List<Comment> SelectCommentsByProject(string pSearchString)
{
   List<Comments> comments = null;

   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pSearchString))
   {
      System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection ecnxn = (System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection)esmEntityManager.Connection;
      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection cnxn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)ecnxn.StoreConnection;

      using (cnxn)
      {
          cnxn.Open();
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
          cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_esm_comment_getByProjectID", cnxn);
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProjectID", pSearchString));

          try
          {
              cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

              SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
              da.SelectCommand = cmd;

              System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
              da.Fill(ds);

              for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
              {
                    if (ds.Tables[i] != null && ds.Tables[i].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                          comments = new List<Comment>();
                          foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in ds.Tables[i].Rows)
                          {
                               Comment comment = new Comment();
                               comment.CommentID = (int)row["CommentId"];
                               comment.ComplianceID = (Guid)row["ComplianceID"];
                               comment.CommentText = (row["Comment"] is DBNull) ? null : row["Comment"].ToString();
                               comment.CreatedBy = (row["CreatedBy"] is DBNull) ? null : row["CreatedBy"].ToString();
                               comment.CreatedOn = Convert.ToDateTime((row["CreatedOn"] is DBNull) ? null : row["CreatedOn"].ToString());
                                    comment.LastModifiedBy = (row["LastModifiedBy"] is DBNull) ? null : row["LastModifiedBy"].ToString();
                               comment.LastModifiedOn = Convert.ToDateTime((row["LastModifiedOn"] is DBNull) ? null : row["LastModifiedOn"].ToString());
                               comment.RequestID = (row["RequestID"] is DBNull) ? null : row["RequestID"].ToString();
                               comment.TypeOfService = (row["TypeOfService"] is DBNull) ? null : row["TypeOfService"].ToString();
                               comment.ProjectID = (row["ProjectID"] is DBNull) ? null : row["ProjectID"].ToString();
                               comment.ProjectManager = (row["PM"] is DBNull) ? null : row["PM"].ToString();
                               comment.TaskManager = (row["TMFullName"] is DBNull) ? null : row["TMFullName"].ToString();
                               comments.Add(comment);
                           }
                     }
              }
                        ds.Dispose();
                        cnxn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            return comments;
}
```

Examing the `List<Comments>` object in debugging, I can see that it contains valid data in the `ProjectID` field. However, I keep getting that error when I try to run it.

Here's (part of) the markup for the ascx.

```
<dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="commentsASPxGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="CommentsDataSource">
   <Columns>
      <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ProjectID" Caption="Project ID" VisibleIndex="7" Name="ProjectID">
      </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
   </Columns>
</dxwgv:ASPxGridView>

<dxprt:ASPxGridViewExporter ID="gridExport" runat="server" GridViewID="commentsASPxGridView"></dxprt:ASPxGridViewExporter>        
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="CommentsDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="SelCommentsByProject"  OnDataBinding="DataBindTest"
    TypeName="ESMWeb.ESMCommentService.CommentServiceClient">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="pProjectId" DbType="String"/>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Can you show smoe relevant piece of code?

Comment: I apologize ahead of time for badly formatted code.

Comment: are you creating the GridView columns programmatically or is it defined in a piece of aspx code? can you put the aspx code, maybe not all but just the projectId column... It can be something simple like the `Eval` refering a property with a typo...

Comment: @Tallmaris The columns are defined in aspx, but I don't think this is the problem is as previous (working) columns are defined in almost the exact same format.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ProjectID a field or property? It must be property in order to work with GridView

Comment: @Yawus, i see this p before ProjectId in couple of places is it intended `pProjectId`?

Comment: Yes, it's the variable that contains the intended search string.